# Where is the "Advanced Control" option in VLC for MAC?

Tags: mac

I'm using VLC on my Mac, but one of the commands/options that continues to arise is for the "Advanced Control" or "Extended Controls" option, which, for the life of me, I can't find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I understand you try to follow instructions written for VLC on Windows which has the Advanced Controls option. Is that right? Unfortunately, VLC for MAC is a very different interface and doesn't have everything its Windows brother has. Maybe if you'd say what exactly it is you want to do someone could find how to do it on VLC on MAC.

Comment: In the Advanced preferences -> Interface, there is an option "Show advanced options". However, I don't see any change when I check it.

Comment: Yep, I also enabled advanced options but apparently that's not the same thing.

Comment: this is called "Extended Controls" in many VLC tutorials. I can't find it either.

Comment: The "Avanced Control" option does not exist on Mac OS. Instead, the controls that it enables are enabled by default, although on a different location. For example, on Windows, the record button only appears when "Advanced Control" is enabled. On Mac OS, there is no record button, but there always is a Record menu item in the Playback menu.  (I wanted to give this as an answer, but SU won't let me because this is a protected question and I have never earned reputation on this SE site; to gain reputation, I need to answer question. -- *sigh*)

Answer (score 5):

*Late Edit*
After much confusion - I had never seen this option before - I found it on Windows, but it just doesn't exist on Mac. The various options exist across the menus & can be key commanded, but there is no dedicated interface add-in for it.
This is still true as at August 2021.

---

*Previous answer*
It's quite simply the Show All button at the bottom left of the prefs pane...

[image]

gives...

[image]

<sup>Right click, open image in new tab, if you want to see full-size</sup>

Comment: But he's seemingly looking for the option "Advanced Controls" (in VLC on Windows it's under View>Advanced Controls) which add some advanced controls on the interface, like the snapshot button etc.

Comment: hmmm... right. Never even noticed that one before. I'll leave the answer up & see if we get clarification as to exactly what's required.